# jQuery UI Slider with a Bootstrap popover changing on slide event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-slider

I am having a problem with bootstrap and jQueryUI, an i think its more of an implementation issue.

I am trying to add a bootstrap popover to a jQueryUI Slider, then on the side event for the slider i am trying to change the text of the popover

below is my code so far.

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#slider1").slider({
        value: 5,
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        step: 1,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            switch(ui.value){
                case 0:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 0';
                break;
                case 1:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 1';
                break;
                case 2:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 2';
                break;
                case 3:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 3';
                break;
                case 4:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 4';
                break;
                case 5:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 5';
                break;
                case 6:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 6';
                break;
                case 7:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 7';
                break;
                case 8:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 8';
                break;
                case 9:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 9';
                break;
                case 10:
                    jQuery("#slider1").data('popover').options.content = 'new content 10';
                break;
            }
            jQuery("#slider1").find(".ui-slider-handle").text(ui.value);
            jQuery("#ctl00_MainContent_rptQuestions_ctl00_sdrQuestion_hdnValue").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    jQuery("#amount1").val("£" + jQuery("#slider1").slider("value"));
});
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var value = jQuery("#slider1").slider("option","value");
    jQuery("#ctl00_MainContent_rptQuestions_ctl00_sdrQuestion_hdnValue").val(value);
    jQuery("#slider1").popover({title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover 5', content: "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!"});
    jQuery("#slider1").popover('show');
    jQuery("#slider1").find(".ui-slider-handle").text(value); 
});
```

So basically what the code above does, is set up a slider from 0 to 10 with an increment of 1, then i set a label on the slider handle to display the current ui value, and change that on the slide event. The problem that i am having is that the bootstrap is not changing when the slider is moved

The bootstrap popover is being initialized, and shows when the page loads, with the correct values, when debugging the JS, the switch statement is being hit and the value is being passed in, it just doesn't seem to change the bs text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the popover does not get informed of you changing the options. Try calling `setContent`:

```
var popover = jQuery("#slider1").data('popover');
popover.options.content = 'new content 10';
popover.setContent();
```

Comment: That seems a little more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i have been working on this since posting the question, and i have indeed found the fix

So inside the switch statment i have added

```
                   case 0:
                       jQuery("#slider1").popover('destroy');
                       jQuery("#slider1").popover({title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover 0', content: "It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!", animation: false});
                       jQuery("#slider1").popover('show');
                   break;
```

I have then done the same for 0 - 10, also by making the animation false, as soon as the value changes the popover dissapears which is exactly what i wanted.

The only slight niggle that i have with it, is that when popover is loaded on page init, the popover appears slightly above where it should, then when the slider is moved the popover drops down a little, but im sure i can toy with it and get it appearing in the same place.

Hope this helps anyone with same issue

Cheers
Joe.